# using phpquery, how to tell if an html string is a single element containing children or just a series of separate elements

Tags: php, phpquery

I am using phpquery to edit an html string and for the best possible output I want to be able to decide if an html string already contains a single parent div.  For example if I have 2 html strings:

string 1:

```
<div class="title">title</div>
<div class="description>description</div>
<div class="number">12345</div>
```

string 2:

```
<div>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="description>description</div>
    <div class="number">12345</div>
</div>
```

If string 2, I don't need to do anything, but in the case of string 1 I would then want to edit the html and add a container div.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems to me there's probabably a better way using DomDocumentFragment

Comment: I am collecting data from a number of separate html files and then using phpQuery to add some custom id's etc.  I then need to check if the html is already incapsulated in one parent div and apply an id to it, or if it already exists apply the id to the that div (to prevent unnecessary nesting).  I am using phpQuery because this is part of a much larger project that already uses phpQuery.